# Wordpress blog header error

Tags: php

I got this problem after I updated the PHP version on the host and I can't figure out why it happened. Also, from time to time, it gets magically fixed.

```php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );?>
```

```
Warning: require(/www/cli17829/cctvonline/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/cli17829/cctvonline/index.php on line 148

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/www/cli17829/cctvonline/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='./:/usr/local/php5.5/lib/php') in /www/cli17829/cctvonline/index.php on line 148
```

Comment: What file is this? It looks like `index.php` but not the current version. You will probably need to talk to your hosting provider about this problem, if the `wp-blog-header.php` file is present. (If not, you might need to reinstall WordPress.)